# Obfuscating AJAX to request random site layout?

Tags: ajax, obfuscation, brute-force

I KNOW that obfuscation is NOT security. However, if I wanted to use multiple ajax requests to change the structure of a page to randomize it based on user input with ever changing elements and ids, would this be sufficient to obfuscate a script that scrapes the page for use, lets say to login in to an admin area? Similar to Google captcha that asks for images to identify, but Google captcha is ineffective, at least in this last attack I have encountered. Been hit pretty hard with excessive brute force attacks and no security plugin exists that is effective in stopping it. So only thing I have tried and seems to work so far is force each login attempt to last 1 minute. Yet even that is not enough and the attacks continue, relentlessly.

I am trying to send a jumbled mess of data back to a php script where all the logic is. I need js because I must watch user actions as they click and solve the puzzles given to them, which hopefully only a human can solve.

The question is specifically on the secure obfuscated transfer of data to a php script that I obfuscate through non conventional means. I KNOW that all ajax requests will show data that is sent (anyone using devtools can see it.) and thats OK. I want to make it such a f'ing mess that no one will waste their time trying to decode its meaning. It will not be a base64 encoded string, it wont be any known algorithm. Also, it is OK if each login to the site backend takes the user 5 minutes to do whether artificially or due to intense processing. The resulting code also will not return anything that can logically be used to reverse engineer its functionality. (the page structure and layout will not look pretty at all. no styling, random html elements added to the page, no structure whatsoever..)

The objective is to use code like this:

// dat contains the string of actions the user has taken - all mouse clicks, key presses etc.. the dat will contain a series of nonsensical data as well that only the receiving script will discard upon processing.

var dat = 'FvV8Zc%v8`j

$.ajax({
method: 'post',
data: dat,
url: '/phplogicscript.php'
});

/*Phplogicscript then sends back the restructured page data and reloads the page saving progress in a session var. After puzzle is solved, the login button appears together with the login scripts being renamed so that they are functional (preventing bypass to known wp scripts) the script name constantly changes so as to avoid detection. */

Comment: Are you sure that it is an attempt to gain access by guessing the password? Because if the google captcher does not work for you then it either indicates that you use it the wrong way, or that it is not an attempt to to gain access but to DDOS. And if it is an DDOS attack then you should try to reduce the server load, and what you describe indicates that it would increase the server load which would make the whole situation even worser.

Comment: You should try to identify if the attacks are from a certain set of IPs, and then block those IPs early for a certain amount of time and send them a `500`, `503` or `509` server response immediatly, before you do anything else in your script. Or even block them using iptables, because if it is an DDOS attempt they might stop at the time when they think that the server is down. And you should report those IP at the abuse email address that belongs to the IP.

Comment: Thanks t.niese, yes I identified all the IPs and they are not TOR based, they are legit IPs from all over Europe, Russia, Ukrain etc.. They are also guessing using 'admin' and other usernames as login names. I doubt that it is a DDOS because the attacks are 2 minutes apart. Captcha is being used the right way, and I've tested it. No server load is not affected, so no DDOS. All the IPs are blocked immediately and I save the list indefinitely. The problem is that they have seemingly endless supply of legit IPs. Blocking TOR was attempted, no success.

Comment: I really doubt that your attempt to solve the problem will help then. That the captcher is solved correctly, and the IPs change every time, and the attacks are two minutes apart, indicates that there is either a problem in your setup, or that it is not a fully bot based breach in attempt but a service using humans to solve the captchas, or any other puzzles. But without analyzing the attacks it is not possible to tell how those attacks are stopped correctly.

Comment: I expect that it might be humans yes. That is the reason behind jumping through the hoops. Initially the attacks was once a minute for hours. I doubt a human do that.. but when I increased difficulty and added captchas, time between attacks increased but they still used same username. Captchas can be defeated by bots, albeit sophisticated ones. I am targeting both bots and humans. Remember that this an admin login form, so wont affect customers. Im trying to eliminate the desire for a human spammer to sit and solve puzzles for 5-10 minutes before each login attempt

Comment: And in the event that people are being paid to attack us, the cost will likely increase because each login attempt will take 5-10 minutes to solve, then wait for another 1-2minutes to actually log in

Comment: On my server I have constantly login attempts every minute or less. But that is not really a problem if the username is wrong. If the username is correct, then choose another one. If they constantly guess the username correctly then you have a real problem. If it is a bruteforce attack to guess the password then it would take (if they have the correct username) impracticable long to figure it out if one password is tested every two minute. Creating a complex solution like yours might not change anything, in the worst case you introduce another security problem because of the complexity.

Comment: And if it is an admin login then you might want to use two factor authentication using OTA, email verification, a browser extension that sends  data with the login that cannot be guessed looking at the website because it is there is no hint about it in there, ...